# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str' help me

Tags: python

I am new to python
I wanted to print '12.6hellohello' in one line
with the input is '4.2 3 2 hello'

This is my code

```
import sys

words = []
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    words.append(line.strip())

e1 = input()
e2 = input()
e3 = input()
e4 = input()

e1 = float(e1)
e2 = int(e2)
e3 = int(e3)
word = e3*e4

print(round(e1*e2,1) + word)
```

I don't understand why when word is separately printed, it works but doesn't work when it is combined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` can print a `float` if it's passed to it, that's not the issue. The issue is, as the error message says, there's no `+` operator between a `float` and a `str`. One way to work around this is to explicitly convert the `float` to a string:

```py
print(str(round(e1*e2,1)) + word)
# Here^
```